# Jquery dialog box appears before clicking button

Tags: jquery, ajax, dialog

I am referring to this example for using dialog boxes. https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form

The problem I face is that before I click on the button to load the dialog box, the form elements are loaded and are shown. Are dialog boxes supposed to function that way? How do I display the dialog box and the form inside the dialog box only when I click the button?

Comment: I think you call a  dialog.dialog( "open" ); on document.ready  rather then button click . Show your mark up an js call to open dialog for further help.

Comment: Could you please post your code here to analyze?

Comment: I am exactly using the code provided as the link.

Comment: @chrisrhyno2003 give us working fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Search in your code for references to `dialog.dialog( "open" );`. If you find more then one then remove the undesired one.

Also do share your code if that doesn't work.